# `cslatex` and TeXLive

Tags: texlive

I have had TeXLive 2016 installed on my machine for some time.  Today, I issued the command `tlmgr update --self --all` and, for some reason, `tlmgr` auto-installed `cslatex`, which generated an error message, I think due to missing hyphenation packages:

```
 [8/9, 00:11/00:11] auto-install: cslatex.x86_64-darwin (18441) [1k] ... done
 [9/9, 00:11/00:11] auto-install: cslatex (40855) [36k] ... done
 tlmgr: package log updated: $PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
 running mktexlsr ...
 done running mktexlsr.
 running updmap-sys ...
 done running updmap-sys.
 regenerating fmtutil.cnf in $PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-dist
 running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex,mfluajit --no-error-if-no-format --byengine tex ...
 done running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex,mfluajit --no-error-if-no-format --byengine tex.
 running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex,mfluajit --byfmt dvilualatex ...
 done running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex,mfluajit --byfmt dvilualatex.
 running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex,mfluajit --byfmt cslatex ...

 tlmgr: fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex,mfluajit --byfmt cslatex failed (status 1), output:
 fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
 fmtutil:   $PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
 fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
 fmtutil:   $PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
 fmtutil [INFO]: writing formats under $PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-var/web2c
 fmtutil [INFO]: --- remaking cslatex with pdftex
 fmtutil: running `pdftex -ini   -jobname=cslatex -progname=cslatex -etex cslatex.ini' ...
 This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (INITEX)
  restricted \write18 enabled.
 entering extended mode

 ($PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/cslatex/base/cslatex.ini jobname=cslatex with pdftex, DVI output initialised.
 ($PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx
 ($PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/texsys.cfg)
 ./texsys.aux found


 \@currdir set to: ./.


 Assuming \openin and \input 
 have the same search path.


 Defining UNIX/DOS style filename parser.

 catcodes, registers, compatibility for TeX 2,  parameters,
 ***** WARNING ******** CSLaTeX is obsolete, don't use it please *****
 ***** You can use ``normal'' LaTeX+Babel or XeLaTeX+polyglossia *****
 LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
 LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
 hacks, control, par, spacing, files, font encodings, lengths,
 ====================================

 Local config file fonttext.cfg used

 ====================================

 ($PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/cslatex/base/fonttext.cfg
 ($PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omlenc.def)
 ($PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)
 ($PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.def)
 ($PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/cslatex/base/il2enc.def)
 ($PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.def)
 ($PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmr.fd)
 ($PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1cmr.fd)
 ($PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/cslatex/base/il2cmr.fd)
 ($PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1cmss.fd)
 ($PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1cmtt.fd))
 ====================================

 Local config file fontmath.cfg used

 ====================================

 ($PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontmath.cfg
 ($PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontmath.ltx
 === Don't modify this file, use a .cfg file instead ===


 ($PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omlcmm.fd)
 ($PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmsy.fd)
 ($PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omxcmex.fd)
 ($PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ucmr.fd)))
 ====================================

 Local config file preload.cfg used

 =====================================

 ($PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/preload.cfg
 ($PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/preload.ltx)) page nos., x-ref, environments, center, verbatim,
 math definitions, boxes, title, sectioning, contents, floats, footnotes,
 index, bibliography, output,
 ===========================================
 Local configuration file hyphen.cfg used
 ===========================================

 ($PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/cslatex/base/hyphen.cfg 
 Loading english hyphenation patterns and exceptions
 ($PATH_TO_TEXLIVE/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphen/hyphen.tex)
 ! OOPS!! Hyphenation patterns file czhyphen.tex for czech not found!.
 \reserved@a ...@gobble \string \czech  not found!}

 l.131 ...                        \@requesthyphens}
                                                   %
 ? 
 ! Emergency stop.
 \reserved@a ...@gobble \string \czech  not found!}

 l.131 ...                        \@requesthyphens}
                                                   %
 No pages of output.
 Transcript written on cslatex.log.
 fmtutil [ERROR]: running `pdftex -ini   -jobname=cslatex -progname=cslatex -etex cslatex.ini </dev/null' return status 1
 fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
 fmtutil [INFO]: Disabled formats: 1
 fmtutil [INFO]: Not selected formats: 14
 fmtutil [INFO]: Failed to build: 1 (pdftex/cslatex)
 fmtutil [INFO]: Total formats: 16
 fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 1
```

It then tries to generate several other Czech formats, with the same error.  Indeed, `csplain`, which `tlmgr show czhyphen` says is the lone distribution containing the file `czhyphen.tex`, is not installed.  I guess that I could install it, but why do I need to do so?  I don't want to write in Czech, and the author of CSLaTeX says:

> Cslatex package is considered obsolete. Users should use instead it the ``normal'' LaTeX with a package which provides a multilingual support.

([source](http://petr.olsak.net/cstex-e.html)).  Is this a bug (either installing it at all, or, if it really must be installed—`tlmgr` thinks it must:

```
$ tlmgr remove cslatex
tlmgr: not removing cslatex.x86_64-darwin, needed by cslatex
tlmgr: not removing cslatex, needed by latex-bin
tlmgr: no packages removed.
tlmgr: action remove returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

—accidentally not bundling the `czhyphen.tex` file)?  What should I do?

EDIT:  Somehow, despite the error, `tlmgr` believed that `cslatex` actually *did* install; so, though I am worried about the state of my system, it seems to be running OK.

EDIT 2 (at the same time, since I ran `tlmgr update --self --all` again just now):  It seems to have been fixed; `cslatex` was auto-removed.

Comment: tl bugs should be sent to mailing list as listed here: https://www.tug.org/texlive/bugs.html  I just did a full update with no error but perhaps it depends on the state that you are updating from.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks for the pointer.  I wasn't sure if this was a bug, and it seemed like TeXLive questions were OK here.  Do you have `csplain` and/or `cslatex` installed?

Comment: It's Ok to post here as far as this site is concerned but unless someone forwards to the list chances are no one who can fix it will see:-)  I have both cs formats already installed so i guess that's the difference

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @KeksDose no but it's been raised on tl list

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks for keeping track.  Somehow `tlmgr` seems to be satisfied with the state of affairs:  despite the reported error, it now reports that `cslatex` *is* installed.  Since I haven't been able to reproduce the error, I couldn't figure out how to report it.  EDIT:  By the way, it seems to have been fixed.  If you want to leave an answer saying this, then I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @KeksDose, running `tlmgr update --self --all` again just auto-removed `cslatex`, so I think someone fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid another question without an answer:

The issue has been solved. An update of texlive included the removal of the package cslatex and cslatex.x86_64-linux and probably as well the removal of any other cslatex.*-bin for other platforms. fmutil (or fmutil-sys) runs without error.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to a discussion of this?  In some sense, the fact that it's fixed is all that matters, but I'd love to know what happened.

Comment: @LSpice Sorry, no link.